# Ubuntu 21.10 External monitor with dock not working on xorg

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, intel-graphics, 21.10, docking

I'm using dock to connect secondary monitor.

It works with wayland and windows.
With xorg it detects display, but fails to display anything.
It works when directly connected to HDMI on laptop
My hardwae:

- Dell Latitude 7420 with intel iGPU.
- [Green Cell AK61](https://greencell.global/en/hub-usb-c/2365-docking-station-adapter-hub-usb-c-hdmi-green-cell-6-ports-for-macbook-pro-dell-xps-lenovo-x1-carbon-and-others.html)
- Benq XL2411

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384

eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm

   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.04  

   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  

   1600x1024     60.17  

   1400x1050     59.98  

   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  

   1280x1024     60.02  

   1440x900      59.89  

   1400x900      59.96    59.88  

   1280x960      60.00  

   1440x810      60.00    59.97  

   1368x768      59.88    59.85  

   1360x768      59.80    59.96  

   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  

   1152x864      60.00  

   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  

   1024x768      60.04    60.00  

   960x720       60.00  

   928x696       60.05  

   896x672       60.01  

   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  

   960x600       59.93    60.00  

   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  

   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  

   840x525       60.01    59.88  

   864x486       59.92    59.57  

   800x512       60.17  

   700x525       59.98  

   800x450       59.95    59.82  

   640x512       60.02  

   720x450       59.89  

   700x450       59.96    59.88  

   640x480       60.00    59.94  

   720x405       59.51    58.99  

   684x384       59.88    59.85  

   680x384       59.80    59.96  

   640x400       59.88    59.98  

   576x432       60.06  

   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  

   512x384       60.00  

   512x288       60.00    59.92  

   480x270       59.63    59.82  

   400x300       60.32    56.34  

   432x243       59.92    59.57  

   320x240       60.05  

   360x202       59.51    59.13  

   320x180       59.84    59.32  

HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-2 connected 1280x800+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm

   1280x800      59.91* 

   1280x768      59.99  

   1024x768      60.00  

   1024x768i     86.96  

   1024x576      59.97  

   832x624       74.55  

   800x600       99.99    85.06    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  

   720x576       50.00  

   848x480       60.00  

   720x480       60.00    59.94  

   640x480      119.99   100.00    85.01    75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  

   720x400       85.04    70.08  

   640x400       85.08  

   640x350       85.08  

HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

when connected directly to HDMI:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384

eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm

   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.04  

   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  

   1600x1024     60.17  

   1400x1050     59.98  

   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  

   1280x1024     60.02  

   1440x900      59.89  

   1400x900      59.96    59.88  

   1280x960      60.00  

   1440x810      60.00    59.97  

   1368x768      59.88    59.85  

   1360x768      59.80    59.96  

   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  

   1152x864      60.00  

   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  

   1024x768      60.04    60.00  

   960x720       60.00  

   928x696       60.05  

   896x672       60.01  

   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  

   960x600       59.93    60.00  

   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  

   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  

   840x525       60.01    59.88  

   864x486       59.92    59.57  

   800x512       60.17  

   700x525       59.98  

   800x450       59.95    59.82  

   640x512       60.02  

   720x450       59.89  

   700x450       59.96    59.88  

   640x480       60.00    59.94  

   720x405       59.51    58.99  

   684x384       59.88    59.85  

   680x384       59.80    59.96  

   640x400       59.88    59.98  

   576x432       60.06  

   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  

   512x384       60.00  

   512x288       60.00    59.92  

   480x270       59.63    59.82  

   400x300       60.32    56.34  

   432x243       59.92    59.57  

   320x240       60.05  

   360x202       59.51    59.13  

   320x180       59.84    59.32  

HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm

   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  

   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  

   1280x1024     75.02  

   1152x864      75.00  

   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  

   1024x768     119.99    75.03    60.00  

   832x624       74.55  

   800x600      119.97    75.00    60.32  

   720x576       50.00  

   720x576i      50.00  

   720x480       60.00    59.94  

   720x480i      60.00    59.94  

   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  

   720x400       70.08  

DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```